# Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the $nth$ roots of unity which subtend a right angle at origin, then prove that n must be of the form $4k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem :

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the $nth$ roots of unity which subtend a right angle at origin, then prove that n must be of the form $4k$

Solution : Here $arg \frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{z_1}{z_2} =cos\frac{\pi}{2}+isin\frac{\pi}{2}$=i I didn't understand this step can anybody please help me on this , will be greatful to him/her.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since the $n^{\text{th}}$  roots of unity are $e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$
we have integers $p,q$ which satisfy
$$
(p-q)\frac{2\pi}{n} = \frac{\pi}2
$$
so
$$
n = 4(p-q)
$$